# Plotting 3D Gaussian distribution only using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, gaussian

I want to plot a 3D gaussian distribution using only numpy.
What I have given:
vector for mean -> mu = [-0.5,-0.5]
covariance matrix -> cov = [[1.0,0],[0,0.5]]

I have problems using matrix multiplication. By separating the equation into 3 parts I managed to do the first two steps: a and b. But iI can only perform c using for loops which I am trying to avoid. How can I do this using numpy functions?

The code that works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R = np.arange(-4,4+1e-9,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(R,R)
x = np.stack((X,Y),axis=2)

mu = np.array([[-0.5],[-0.5]])
cov = np.array([[1.,0],[0,0.5]])

a = x-mu.T
b = np.matmul(a,np.linalg.inv(cov))
c = np.zeros(X.shape)
for i in range(0,81):
    for j in range(0,81):
        c[i,j] = np.dot(b[i,j],a[i,j])

P_xw1 = 1/(np.sum(np.exp(-0.5*c)))*np.exp(-0.5*c)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X,Y,P_xw1,s=2)
```

Comment: `c = (a  * b).sum(axis=2)`

Comment: Alternatively, `np.einsum('ijk, ijk -> ij', a, b)` which is faster at the expense of clarity.

Comment: Thanks for both the answers! I've tried einsum in every possible way BUT this one... and the construction of the one above is very helpful in another problem I have!

Comment: `c = np.sum(b*a, axis=2)`